# How to use pie charts in a query mobile?

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a dashboard application in jquery mobile  and I want to implement pie chart in that. can somebody  help me through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some graph libraries for jQuery like:

- Flot: http://www.flotcharts.org/ (pie chart example: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html)
- jqPlot: http://www.jqplot.com/index.php (pie chart example: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to fetch my data through json format and show it in chart. I want to create my local json object and call it through http:// format. how can i do that?

Comment: See documentation in the links Pablo has sent you